# Docker-compose postgres cant init my tables in newly created database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am trying to automate the INIT process in Docker so whenever I docker-compose up in an empty data directory it will create two DBS 1st one is Airflow and the second one is my test DB so for instance when I docker-compose up Postgres run the first SQL file in my new test DB to create tables. However, it didn't run the insert SQL files I have already mounted in docker-entry point what is does it run those files in the Airflow database can anyone tell me how to insert all metadata tables in my Test Database instead of airflow one thanks

My docker-compose file

```yaml
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: airflow ,docker_airflow

    ports: 
    - "5432:5432"

    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/1._ddl.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1._ddl.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/2._init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2._init.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/3._props.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3._props.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/4.ge_ddl.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4.ge_ddl.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/5.ge_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/5.ge_init.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/6._be_lu_nl.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/6._be_lu_nl.sql
      - ../data-platform/db/metadata/init/7._registration_nl_lifecycle.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/7._registration_nl_lifecycle.sql

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
```

Comment: Have you tried adding instruction to psql to connect to the other database in the scripts? (`\c somedb`)

Comment: i have 7 scripts and i use \connect docker (DB name :D) 
BEGIN; in the first .SQL it creates table  but when it goes to second one it says the schema does not exist and I also used connect in this script as well

Comment: They’re run separately so each one needs to have the connection set in them if they want to target another database than the default

Comment: okay sue i will try this btw is my syntax correct like is m using this \connect db_name and then  BEGIN;

Comment: Can you run two separate database containers?  That could resolve this ambiguity.  Also consider running some of the "create tables" logic through a database-migration system in your application, which you'll be able to re-run if you change your schema.

Comment: I was gonna first but the requirement was to build databases in a single Postgres image/container. Actually you are right but i was focusing on DOCKER-compose to run these scripts when data directory is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the scripts you need to set each one up with the correct information. They’re run with the default credentials which means they also connect to the default database.

You can add to the beginning of each file instructions for psql to connect to the desired database with `\c somedb`. It needs to be in each script since they’re run separately and won’t hold any information between runs.